# Is there a one-threaded alternative to Timeout?

Tags: ruby

There is a Ruby class [`Timeout`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) that terminates the execution of a block after a certain amount of seconds:

```
Timeout.timeout(5) {
  # Some long-running code...
}
```

The problem is that every time I call `timeout()` it starts a new `Thread`. It's pretty expensive (time and memory) operation. Would be much more effective to re-use an existing thread. Are there any Gems for that?

Comment: New Thread is not a major issue: https://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/